# how to add data in datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to add data dynamically in datatable.I have initialized table on document.ready and created an instance of it.After that, I am trying to add data in the table using instance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Initialize tooltips
    table_sgdFile_list_linked = $('#sgdFile_list_linked').DataTable({
    bSort: false,
    destroy:true,
    bLengthChange: false,
    pageLength: 4,
    columns: [{
        title: "Name"
      },
      {
        title: "Action"
      }
    ]
  });
  });
```

I am trying to bind the data

```js
table_sgdFile_list_linked.data(dataSet)
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? server-side? a dom element?

Comment: I am making one ajax call to get the data and create table using that.@markpsmith

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = $('#my-table-html-id').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "paging": true,
    "bLengthChange" : true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "pageLength": 10,
    "info": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "ajax": "PATH-OF-MY-API",
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                var html = data + " Modified!";
                return html;
            },
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 1 //Last column
        },
    ],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

to add 1 row: `table_sgdFile_list_linked.row.add(rowJson).draw();`

to add multiple rows: `table_sgdFile_list_linked.rows.add(rowsJson).draw();`

Answer (score 0):

following worked for me :

table_sgdFile_list_linked.clear().draw();
$('#sgdFile_list_linked').dataTable().fnAddData(trHTML);